# Eclipse Java code assist breaks after declaration

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently I am having a problem with Eclipse Code Assist breaking after declaring a variable of a certain type. Furthermore, removing the offending variable declaration does nothing to fix code assist, the problem just persists. Short of copying the code (without the offending statement), deleting the file, and then making a new one and pasting the code in, nothing seems to work. I have read about changing the settings in the preference menu, deleting the type cache, etc. but none of this works. There are no project errors. I've abstained from posting any source as I am not sure what information would be of actual use.

Comment: welcome to the joys of eclipse.  Try updating to the latest version, if it is not already

Comment: You could debug Eclipse from Eclipse, and file what you found on Bugzilla... (at least that was what I did when I found a bug)

Comment: Which version are you using? You can try a reinstall.

Comment: I'm using Juno. The problem appeared after having to kill the eclipse process (I think). Before that it worked fine. Another symptom was that all my plugins had disappeared (I don't know if they were deleted or eclipse simply wouldn't detect them), but I just reinstalled them and everything else works fine now, it's only this project that seems to keep having problems.

Comment: What language are you even working on?  And what kind of project is it?

Comment: I am working with JEE along with Maven and the Jrebel plugin.